# Sleep function not keyboard-wakeable

Tags: windows-7, sleep

When I press the Sleep button on my keyboard, I get the Sleep I want, which allows the computer to wake up from a mouse click or key press. My wife is used to her desktop shortcut, however, and when I create one for sleep, it goes into hybrid sleep that will only be woken up by hitting the power button. In fact, any other implementation of 'sleep' puts the computer basically into hibernation, or possibly hybrid sleep.

How can I get the desktop shortcut to put the computer into a keyboard-wakeable state like the physical button? It's a Windows 7 PC.

Comment: You need to list the actual command the shortcut invokes. You also need to relate your existing power configuration settings.

Comment: If you're using an USB keyboard, you should make sure it is allowed to wake up the computer in Device Manager; otherwise it will be powered down during sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use hibernate you could disable it all together. Find the command prompt i start menu, right click and choose "Run as administrator". At the command prompt type "powercfg.exe /hibernate off" without the quotes and close the command prompt window. Now your computer should always sleep instead of hibernate.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I had already set Hibernate>Never in my Power Mgmt options, so I didn't think I had to worry about that, but using the command you mentioned fixed it so the shortcut (C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep) worked liked I wanted it to.